# amplify push lambda (python) embed lot of useless package

Tags: aws-lambda, virtualenv, aws-amplify

I did the following with default value:

```
$ amplify init
$ amplify add function
$ mkvirtualenv --python=`which python3.8` p3.8
$ workon p3.8
$ amplify push
```

It uploads the function as expected but I cannot display its code on amplify console because :

> The deployment package of your Lambda function "testfunc-dev" is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function.

If I download the content I get the following files:

[image]

I upload the boilerplate `hello from lambda`, I want nothing but my `index.py` file in my function. How can I achieve that ?